# using regex to replace the name of the columns

Tags: java, regex, coldfusion, lucee

I am using a procedure to rename the tablename which is working well. The SPX handles all the things of the Keys and the constraints and that is quite well. My Only issue is I am using the replace to change the tablename but the problem is happening if the column has the same name as tablename and it is also changing that and that is where the code is failing

Here is an example of that

```
create Table dbo.States(
int int not null identity, 
States nvarchar(100))
```

So if i am changing `States` to `Provinces`, It is also renaming the column which i do not want,

Checking if i can use regex to skip reaming there and and for other places it should keep replacing as is

I am using it like this

```
Replace(mytableString, 'States', 'provinces','all')
```

Comment: Depending on how complicated the SQL string could be besides your example, you could perhaps just do `Replace(mytableString, 'States', 'provinces','one')` to replace only the first occurrence of `States`.

Comment: I invite @TonyJunkes to submit his comment as an answer.

Comment: Converted my comment to an answer.

Comment: Do all the relevant sql commands include the schema in the tablename like you have in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my initial comment,

Without knowing if/how complicated your real-world SQL may be, you can do

```
Replace(mytableString, 'States', 'provinces','one')
```

to replace only the first occurrence of `States`.

**UPDATE:**

Borrowing the regex from Arvind's Java example answer...

If the SQL string is more complex (e.g. an `ALTER` statement ahead of the `CREATE` statement etc.), you can use a regular expression with a positive look ahead to match `States` on the left side of an opening `(`.

Consider this example:

```
result = reReplace(exampleSQL, 'States(?=\()', 'Provinces', 'all');
```

You can run an [example code at TryCF.com](https://trycf.com/gist/ca43aa55d1201e2202ecea5f73220dd8/acf2018?theme=monokai)

**UPDATE 2:**

Given the example provided in the comments where the SQL string is more complex and the table may be wrapped in square brackets, you can do the following to match `States` with or without the `[]`s and it including a `(`:

```
reReplaceNoCase(exampleSQL, '\[?States\]?(?=\()', 'Provinces', 'all')
```

You can run an [example code at TryCF.com](https://trycf.com/gist/c4ed802b5339b0fb011cbb2f6696372b/acf2018?theme=monokai)

**UPDATE 3:**

To followup from my misunderstanding that *every table reference* of `states` needs to be updated, here is a possibly cleaner approach over regex that can be accomplished in 2 passes.

```
// Replace all instances of states as a table declaration
result = replaceNoCase(exampleSQL, '[dbo].[states]', '[dbo].[provinces]', 'all');
// Replace all instances of states as a pk/constraint
result = replaceNoCase(result, '_states', '_provinces', 'all')
```

Comment: works, but if i have other commands like alter, its failing

Comment: It does work in your example, but i have an example like this https://trycf.com/gist/4df979c4e5840a80436f61968de7c23e/lucee5?theme=monokai . it is not working here

Comment: alter is after the create

Comment: @JimSofbrez, ok these are the kind of details/examples we need at the start if anyone is going to be able to help completely. Otherwise it's just a shot in the dark.So given your linked SQL example, what all would you be expecting to update? Is it just the create table? You could still modify the regex slightly to match that to include the brackets. If there are other parts in that string, you may need to consider a couple iterations of reReplace() with modified regex for each pass. Regex is never fun to maintain when you try to do everything in one shot for large blocks of strings.

Comment: Thanks But i think it only hanged the value in create and not in other areas, what was question was it should not change the value within the create, but everywhere else

Comment: Like the alter, constraints, etc etc, only the column which is inside the states table should not be changed

Comment: Ok fair, I misunderstood the desire to change all table names in the string. Going after the table name and items like contraints in one pass may be tricky. What CFML engine/version are you using (ColdFusion or Lucee)? I want to narrow down any restrictions.

Comment: I am on Lucee latest build

Comment: I updated my answer to include feeding the SQL through reReplace() twice to replace the necessary areas. I think it's possible with regex, but I couldn't come up with anything thorough enough. If I think of a way, I'll share it here.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know `ColdFusion` but I can suggest you a Java solution. You can use the regex, `States(?=\()` to match the table name, `States` and replace it with the desired string e.g. `provinces`. Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/tGmWbd/1) to see a demo and explanation of the regex.

**Java code:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sql = "create Table dbo.States(\n" + 
                        "int int not null identity, \n" + 
                        "States nvarchar(100))";

        String regex = "States(?=\\()";

        String result = sql.replaceAll(regex, "provinces");

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
create Table dbo.provinces(
int int not null identity, 
States nvarchar(100))
```

Comment: Your regex string appears to be what the OP may be looking for. I have applied it in CFML for them to test out. Cheers for that. +1

Comment: Thanks, @TonyJunkes for supporting it.